Is there a way to use a queue like RabbitMQ to send data from strapi over to my custom backend
I'm using Strapi 4 and I was wondering if I can send data from stapi whenever there's a create/update/delete from my strapi admin to my backend via a queue? Is such a solution viable?

Yes, you can use a queue system like RabbitMQ to send data from Strapi to your custom backend
First, ensure that you have queue system set up and running (like RabbitMQ).
Configure Strapi Lifecycle Hooks: You can use Strapi's lifecycle hooks to trigger events whenever there are changes in your content (before/after create, update, delete, etc..)
Kindly check out the Strapi documentation on lifecycle hooks for more details:
Strapi Lifecycle Hooks Documentation https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/models#lifecycle-hooks
Implement the Producer in Strapi
Within your Strapi project, use a library like amqplib to connect to RabbitMQ.
In your lifecycle hook, send a message to the RabbitMQ queue whenever a relevant event occurs.
last part, in your custom backend, create a consumer to process the messages from the RabbitMQ queue.
